# How to View the IP routing table

Tags: linux, networking, ip, route, sql

How can I see `ip routes` I've added with `ip route add default via x.x.x.55 table test1`
for example I added `199 test1` and `198 test2` and `197 test3` to /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

then I run:

```
ip route add default via x.x.x.55 table test1
ip route add default via x.x.x.55 table test2
ip route add default via x.x.x.55 table test3
```

then when I check `route -n`, this is the only thing I see

```
x.x.x.x   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 tun0
```

additional test

```
ip route flush x.x.x.55
ip route add default via x.x.x.55 table test1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

Where is the test1, test2 and test3 I've added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stop using the `netstat` and `route` commands, they will just confuse you and they don't have the necessary functionality anyway.

To view the basic IPv4 routing table:

```
ip route
```

To view a specific table:

```
ip route list table test1
```

To view *everything*:

```
ip route list table all
```

---

And remember that these arguments can be abbreviated as long as they remain uniquely identifiable:

```
ip r l t all
```

Comment: Confusing but true.  Netstat -rn and route are not fully deprecated but neither are they fully functional in light of iproute2.